# How to simplify my program in Python, using recursion?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am not a programmer. I've been learning how to program in Python. I've written the program which checks whether all opening brackets and all closing brackets match in a string. I used the recursion in this program. But this code contains too many lines. I want to simplify this program but the recursion should remain! I've already written another version of this programs in which I used a while-loop. Please advise on how to simplify the program, using **the recursion**, if possible.

> ```
> [] True
> ] False
> [ False
> ][ False
> [[]] True
> [[][]] True
> ][][ False
> etc.
> ```

```
 # s should be a string; please pass zero as the second argument

def check_br(s, opening_br):  

 length=len(s)

 if length==0:
    print ("error")
    return None 

 if length==1 and s[0]=="[":
    opening_br+=1
    return opening_br==0

 if length==1 and s[0]=="]":
    opening_br-=1
    return opening_br==0

 if s[0]=="[" and s[0] != s[1]:
    if length==2:
        return opening_br==0
    else:
        new_s=s[2:]    # form a new string by removing two leading chars. 
        return check_br(new_s, opening_br)

 elif s[0]=="]":
    if opening_br>0:         
        opening_br-=1
        new_s=s[1:]       #form a new string by removing one leading char.

        return check_br(new_s, opening_br)
    else:
        return False

 elif s[0]=="[" and s[0] == s[1]:
        new_s=s[1:]       #form a new string by removing one leading char.
        opening_br+=1
        return check_br(new_s, opening_br)
```

To check the correctness of the program, I used , as an example, the following in the script:

```
m=']][['
print(check_br(m,0))
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out for further reading that pretty much any loop can be converted into a recursive call, and vica-versa (referring to @Marvo's answer). Also Just as an aside, this particular problem is (IMAO) much easier to solve using a stack were you push any open brackets and when you find a close bracket, pop and compare if they are the same type.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks. I'll try to solve it by means of a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite a long program for a litte counting. You don't have to do more than to count the currently opened brackets. This number should be 0 at the end and never become negative.

Recursion usually does not make things less complicated, in my opinion.

```
def check_br(s,count=0):
    for c in s:
        if c == "[":
            count += 1
        elif c == "]":
            count -= 1
            if count < 0:
                return False
    return not count
```

That's the recursive version:

```
def check_br(s,count=0):
    if not s:
        return not count
    else:
        if s[0] == "[":
            count += 1
        elif s[0] == "]":
            count -= 1
            if count < 0:
                return False
        return check_br(s[1:],count)
```

Let's make a test:

```
for teststring in ("[] True",
                   "] False",
                   "[ False",
                   "][ False",
                   "[[]] True",
                   "[[][]] True",
                   "][][ False"):
    print(teststring," --> ",check_br(teststring))
```

Result:

```
[] True  -->  True
] False  -->  False
[ False  -->  False
][ False  -->  False
[[]] True  -->  True
[[][]] True  -->  True
][][ False  -->  False
```

Comment: Just added the recursive version for comparison.

Comment: the recursive version gives an incorrect result when s="[" , s="[[[[[[[[[[", s="[[[]", s="[[[[[]]]". When count>0 and if not s at the same time, the result is True.

Comment: I think the line `return not count` should be inserted after `if not s` .